# How to make link in python Tabulate? see my following code

Tags: python, tabulate

I have this code
Where I want to hyperlink urlvalue to the title

[image]

I tried to insert HTML hyperlink but got exception error...

But I like to get hyperlink in the table with two values like Title will be clickable with url value

Comment: [Please do not post images of code or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Please the full error traceback if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Use 'unsafehtml' format like this.

```
tabulate(output, tablefmt='unsafehtml')
```

But don't forget to escape other cell values by yourself.(using the `html.escape()`)